# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing in ast.py while converting text into list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, syntax-error, eof

I have a `.txt` file named `my_file` containing following lines of strings:

```
[(11.0795, 16), (12.0354, 16)]
[(11.0795, 19), (12.0354, 19)]
[(11.0795, 16), (12.0354, 16)]
```

Now, I am using the following code to convert lines into lists of tuples:

```
import ast


file_name = open('/home/username/Desktop/my_file.txt', "r")
lines = file_name.read().split('\n')
xy = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[0].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
xz = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[1].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
yz = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[2].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
print(xy[0])
print(yz[1])
print(xz[0][0])
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 48, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I am not sure why in most cases everything works, but in the case of this particular file not. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you going through that crazy `str(lines[0].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'")` contortion when the original string is already in exactly the format you need?

Comment: The text file is being filled while some code is running. This is why the contents are considered strings and not an actual list object.

Comment: "The text file is being filled while some code is running" - first, that seems kind of weird and quite likely related to the problem, if the file isn't completely written by the time you try to read it. Second, that still wouldn't require the whole `str(lines[0].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'")` business.

Comment: The file is actually completely written by the time I try to read it. But, if I don't do it, then I am left with a 'str' object which is not helpful for me to do some calculations on.

Comment: The `ast.literal_eval` part is the only part responsible for parsing the string into a list of tuples. The `str(lines[0].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'")` part is a bunch of unnecessary complexity that happens to do nothing, but would corrupt your data if the file actually had any quotation marks in it.

Comment: I am not sure what it is , but the above code worked fine for me . I am on Python 3.6.5 and I get the following result `[(11.0795, 16), (12.0354, 16)] [(11.0795, 19), (12.0354, 19)] [(11.0795, 16), (12.0354, 16)]` when I run the code

Comment: Considering that you haven't posted a [mcve], we cannot confirm that the file is completely written by the time you try to read it. (We're not going to take your word for it - if you correctly understood everything your program was doing, you wouldn't be here.)

Comment: Files are already stored in some area and I am only accessing them. So, I am sure that I am not creating them. But I will make a MWE.

Comment: I copied the content of the file that is not working to some other file on my desktop and I ran the code as it appears above and everything works fine. So, the problem is the with original version of my_file. I don't know what is wrong with it. This is weird.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with you not ignoring empty lines in your file, check my answer below and see if it makes sense to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that when you split on newline via `\n`, you are also getting empty lines in your output, and when you try to run `ast.literal_eval` on them, they throw an exception.

Let's run your original code, here I am storing the content in a string instead of a file.

```
s = """
[(11.0795, 16), (12.0354, 16)]
[(11.0795, 19), (12.0354, 19)]
[(11.0795, 16), (12.0354, 16)]
"""

import ast

lines = s.split('\n')
xy = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[0].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
xz = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[1].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
yz = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[2].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
print(xy[0])
print(yz[1])
print(xz[0][0])
```

Now I do get the error you are getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/deveshks/PycharmProjects/DevProjects/script.py", line 11, in <module>
    xy = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[0].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Now if I modify the line where I am splitting the text to ignore empty lines, the code runs perfectly.

```
s = """
[(11.0795, 16), (12.0354, 16)]
[(11.0795, 19), (12.0354, 19)]
[(11.0795, 16), (12.0354, 16)]
"""

import ast


lines = [line.strip() for line in s.split('\n') if line.strip() != '']
xy = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[0].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
xz = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[1].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
yz = ast.literal_eval(str(lines[2].split('"')).strip("[]").strip("'"))
print(xy[0])
print(yz[1])
print(xz[0][0])
```

I now get the output

```
(11.0795, 16)
(12.0354, 16)
11.0795
```

Comment: Thanks Devesh, yes that was the case.

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help!